# "I had back pain since 1995" or "I had back pain from 1995"?

Tags: word-choice, tense, past-tense, since

I've had a doubt for some time!

> I had back pain **since** 1995, phew! It's over! (**I don't have anymore**)

Is "**since**" suitable with my sentence? Or should I use "**from**"?

I heard that we shouldn't use **since** as we are talking about past action.

Comment: There are different meanings for **since**. In your sentence, it does not mean **because**. I would use **from** for the *reason*: "I had back pain from an accident."

Comment: Even after a point a point time?

Comment: We use _since_, with a date or with reference to a past incident. 'I have had back pain since 1995' or 'since the accident' (until now). 'I had had back pain since 1995, but the treatment I had last month cured it.'

Comment: Yes but about the simple past? I wanted to say : I had back pain, now I don't have anymore

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You definitely want to use since in this sentence. You would use from to explain where you got your back pain.

In your sentence, you might want to consider using the helping verb "have had" because the second part of your sentence is in present tense, and you want to stay parallel.

An example would be:

I have had back pain since 1995 from an accident at baseball.

"Since" is also a conjunction and you could use it to start your sentence:

Since 1995, I have had continuous back pain. Phew! I'm glad that's over.

Another example: I have had that book since 1995, but I gave it away in 2010, so I never read it.

Comment: Do you mean that I could use "I have had" ,which normally mean that events are still true, even if I no longer have back pain, as long as I mention at the end that the event  is finished?

Comment: "had" is simple past tense and "have had" is Present Perfect tense.  The second part of your sentence.  "Phew, it's over!" is in present tense.  You want to stay parallel.

Comment: Would it be correct If I'd said : I owned it since 1990 (but I gave it in 2010 wich mean I haven't had it anymore for a longtime)

Comment: But you haven't given it away.

Comment: Sorry it is for the exemple I talked about anything else, a book for exemple...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually my question is : Can I use since with the past, but I think you answered me. Thanks

Comment: Oh, you owned the book since 1990, but you gave it away in 2010.  You understand "since", correctly, but now  you should study "give" and "give away"

Comment: Many thanks, I did : given with free charges?

Answer (score 0):

Since is the most appropriate form.  I have had back pain since 1995.  You would use from only in situations where you are setting a date range.  I have had back pain from 1995 until today.

Comment: Yes but I talked about the past I wrote "I had" and "past action" is it the same rules?

Comment: Yes.  You can`t use from unless you set two time periods, which can include the present but you have to state that.

Comment: I see.. but : I had a lot of trouble from the very first day I met her (past) would be correct?